# Move cells in column automatically up when delete first cells

Tags: excel, vba

I move automatically a column (6000rows) in an excel sheet. it only has the value 1 or 0. I want automatically that excel see the first 1 in the column and then delete everything above this row that contains the value 1. When above the first 1 is deleted I want to move everything up.

I have tried to use some code but I can only detect the first row that contains the first 1. I hope that someone can help my to develop some code.

I have find some code to find the first value 1 in the column.

Thanks,
Mitchel Gommers

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim intMyVal As Integer
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim strRowNoList As String

intMyVal = 1 'Value to search for, change as required.
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column A, change as required.

For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow) 'Starting cell is A2, change as required.

    If cell.Value = intMyVal Then
        If strRowNoList = "" Then
        strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row
        Else
        strRowNoList = strRowNoList & ", " & cell.Row
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `Range("--").Delete xlShiftUp` to move the cells up. In your case**

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim intMyVal As Integer
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim strRowNoList As String

intMyVal = 1 'Value to search for, change as required.
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'Search Column A, change as required.

For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow) 'Starting cell is A2, change as required.

    If cell.Value = intMyVal Then

        Range("A2:A" & cell.row - 1).Delete xlShiftUp
        Exit For

    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

This will delete everything above the First 1 in the column A.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it without using a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        rw = Application.Evaluate("=MATCH(1,A:A,0)")
        On Error GoTo 0

        If rw < 3 Then Exit Sub

        .Rows("2:" & rw-1).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to use exact MATCH.

Comment: To be on a safer side, I have added it :)